# Unity Admobs not working on android devices

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, admob

So i have tested the ads on  iOS devices its working absolutely fine!

but when apk build and install on android devices Admobs ads doesn't even show!

the Adcontroller Script i'm using for integration of ads!

can anyone explain what is causing this problem. it would be appreciated!

thanks

public class AdController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public static AdController instance;

private BannerView bannerView;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;


void Awake (){
    MakeSingleton ();
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Start () {


    MakeSingleton ();


    RequestBanner ();
    RequestInterstitial ();

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string appId = "ca-app-pub-3454534660788114~3231414565";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string appId = "ca-app-pub-3454534660788114~6021229439";
    #else
    string appId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);

    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

}

void MakeSingleton() {
    if (instance != null) {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    } else {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

    }

}





private void RequestBanner()
{
    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3454534660788114/6674059459";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3454534660788114/5829657741";
    #else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Clean up banner ad before creating a new one.
    if (this.bannerView != null)
    {
    this.bannerView.Destroy();
    }

    // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
    this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    // Register for ad events.
    RegisterDelegateForBanner ();

    // Load a banner ad.
    this.bannerView.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
    }


    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3454534660788114/1152046133";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3454534660788114/5254942671";
    #else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Clean up interstitial ad before creating a new one.
    if (this.interstitial != null)
    {
    this.interstitial.Destroy();
    }

    // Create an interstitial.
    this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    // Register for ad events.
    RegisterDelegateForInterstitial ();


    // Load an interstitial ad.
    this.interstitial.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
    }

    private AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
    {
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
    .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
    .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
    .AddKeyword("game")
    .SetGender(Gender.Male)
    .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
    .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
    .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
    .Build();
    }

    void RegisterDelegateForBanner(){

    this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleAdLoaded;
    this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleAdFailedToLoad;
    this.bannerView.OnAdOpening += this.HandleAdOpened;
    this.bannerView.OnAdClosed += this.HandleAdClosed;
    this.bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleAdLeftApplication;

    }

    void UnregisterDelegateForBanner(){

    this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleAdLoaded;
    this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad -= this.HandleAdFailedToLoad;
    this.bannerView.OnAdOpening -= this.HandleAdOpened;
    this.bannerView.OnAdClosed -= this.HandleAdClosed;
    this.bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication -= this.HandleAdLeftApplication;

    }

    void RegisterDelegateForInterstitial(){

    this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
    this.interstitial.OnAdOpening += this.HandleInterstitialOpened;
    this.interstitial.OnAdClosed += this.HandleInterstitialClosed;
    this.interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;

    }


    void UnRegisterDelegateForInterstitial(){

    this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad -= this.HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
    this.interstitial.OnAdOpening -= this.HandleInterstitialOpened;
    this.interstitial.OnAdClosed -= this.HandleInterstitialClosed;
    this.interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication -= this.HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;

    }
    public void ShowBanner(){
    bannerView.Show ();
    }


    public void ShowInterstitial(){
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded ()) {

        interstitial.Show ();

    } else {
        RequestInterstitial ();
    }

    }



    public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    ShowBanner ();
    }

    public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
    UnregisterDelegateForBanner ();
    RequestBanner ();
    }

    public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }

    public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    UnregisterDelegateForBanner ();
    RequestBanner ();

    }

    public void HandleAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }






    public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }

    public void HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
    UnRegisterDelegateForInterstitial ();
    RequestInterstitial ();

    }

    public void HandleInterstitialOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    UnregisterDelegateForBanner ();
    RequestBanner ();

    }

    public void HandleInterstitialLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us the output of this?

Also check if you completed your billing information in your ADMOB profile, it seems that you can't get it working unless you fill it.

It seems also that you are not  calling, ShowInterstitial() ?